# htaccess rewrite complicated image subfolder to correct images

Tags: .htaccess, subdirectory

how can i forward such a complicated image folder (which is different for each image!) in the old server to the new server with statistical picture url?

wat always stays the same on the old server are the first 2 folders:

`/storage/images/`

here completely (old server) picture url with **example.jpg**:

`www.domain.com/storage/images/image?remote=https://domain/WebRoot/Site26/Sites/3242c7c4-9237-41d1-b0e1-5e618f6c276d/6595/224C/767D/9745/A7A7/0A48/3580/740D/`**example.jpg**`&site=3242c7c4-9237-41d1-b0e1-5e618f6c276d&width=600&height=2560`

and new picture url (very friendly!)

`www.domain.com/pictures/product/1/`**example.jpg**`

the new url is statistical and all images are included there. i need only the filename (**example.jpg**), without string after and before. than can i make my rewrite rule, thanks!

Comment: Well, you implement a rewriting or redirection rule in the old http host that captures the actual file name that is referenced inside the query string and use that captured string to build the target URL you want to rewrite / redirect to. That will only work if the new path `/pictures/product/1/` is static, of course, because there is nothing in the old URL that carries this information, as far as I can see. So what is your actual question here?

Comment: the new url is statistical and all images are included there. my question is, how can i first recognize the folder “/storage/images/” and second the file name (example.jpg) so that i can forward it correctly?

Answer (score 0):

From the comment I understand that you simply ask how to rewrite such a request. There are literally *thousands* of existing answers for this here on SO. But to make it easy for this might be an approach you could start with:

Either as an internal rewrite *if* both old and new URLs are received by the same http host inside the same http server:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (?:(^|&))remote=.+/([^/]+)(?:(&|$))
RewriteRule ^/?storage/images/image$ /pictures/product/1/%1 [L,QSD]
```

Or as an external redirection in case those are separate http hosts:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (?:(^|&))remote=.+/([^/]+)(?:(&|$))
RewriteRule ^/?storage/images/image$ https://example.com/pictures/product/1/%1 [R=301,L,QSD]
```

Both rules can be implemented in either the central configuration of the http host (preferable for reasons of efficiency and reduced complexity) or, if you do not have access to that, in a *distributed* configuration file. Such file, typically called ".htaccess" should be place in the folder that serves as `DOCUMENT_ROOT` in the http host and it has to be readable by the http server process. Obviously you also need to take care that the rewriting module is actually loaded in the http server and that you enabled the interpretation of such rules for that location by means of the `AllowOverride` directive.

---

Some advice:

Do not blindly copy something like that. It is important that you actually understand the details of such things. You need to be able to adjust it to your specific setup and detailed needs. You won't get around working through some tutorial to be familiar with the tools you are trying to use.

Also having the documentation at hand is of great value, here the documentation of the apache http server's rewriting module. As typical for OpenSource software it is of excellent quality and comes with helpful examples: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html

Comment: "From the comment I understand that you simply ask how to rewrite such a request." => no! i need only the filename (example.jpg), without string after and before. than can i make my rewrite rule, thanks!

Comment: @od_ That _is_ rewriting a request, actually. And what the rules in this answer do.